# Materialize modal is not working in Angular

Tags: materialize

[ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQwor.png)
[html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sCIR.png)
This is the code in my project. When clicking on modal button it's not showing anything.

HTML:

```html
<button data-target="modal1" class="btn modal-trigger">Modal</button>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
declear const M;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you imported the css,js correctly? can you give us more details about your code? e.g How does your .html looks like and how is your folder structure etc?

Comment: i imported css and js

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

Comment: is the importing at the beginning of your HTML or at the end of the html? How does your console.log look like on the browser? And have you required your javascript after the cdn is loaded?

Comment: i  imported CSS and JS at the beginning of html file.i am not loading any javascript after the cdn is loaded

Comment: put the js after the CDN is loaded. Because it cannot refer to the functions unless it's been loaded. So it should be something like:  <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/…>, then <script src="myscript.js"> </script>

Comment: and also can you show me your developers console in your browser. it's hard to debug without any concrete informations

Comment: Is this TS file? if it's TS file you can't refer to that from plain js. You have to transpile it first to javascript

Comment: this is angular application?? then you can't even do that use import * {} in the app.module.ts file and create a service for downloading it from CDN